# Model or theory for liquids thermodynamics?

Tags: liquid-state

Is there any theory or model for the thermal expansion of liquids, different pressure and temperatures?
 I don't know if it is right to say "liquids thermodynamics" but i can only find Phonon theory of liquids (2012) and old Frenkel`s theory.

I should model accurately the liquid hydraulic power transferring system and it goes in different temperatures. And there is one problem: There is extra heat from outside the system, and I can not calculate how much heat converted to work.

Carnot does not give the right result if I think the work of the liquids.

Thanks, and have a nice weekend.

S

Comment: Which kind of liquid you are interested in?

Comment: yes there is, and the core of the model is something called the equation of state for the liquid.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe Tait`s equation, bulkmodulus and thermal expansion value help me, and normal hydraulic power calculation. 
There is a certain flow and pressure, and end of the line is hydraulic motor. The heat comes from outside in the flow, and of course the flow rate increases (heat expansion). I reduce bulkmodulus of this, and then I get a real increase in flow. i.e. Motor power increases as the flow increases. It is easy. 
I thought there would be a formula for " liquids thermodynamics or Work on the thermal expansion of liquids ", like for gases. But it's hard to do.